# Node.js - Craigslist bulk post api (Failed to parse rss)

Tags: xml, node.js, api, rss, craigslist

I am using the bulk post api for craigslist. I wrote a quick script that looks like this:

```
var https = require('https');
var posting = '<?xml version="1.0"?><rdf:RDF xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cl="http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0"><channel><items><rdf:li rdf:resource="NYCBrokerHousingSample1"/><rdf:li rdf:resource="NYCBrokerHousingSample2"/></items><cl:auth username="example@example.com" password="example" accountID="14"/></channel><item rdf:about="NYCBrokerHousingSample1"><cl:category>fee</cl:category><cl:area>nyc</cl:area><cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea><cl:neighborhood>Upper West Side</cl:neighborhood><cl:housingInfo price="1450" bedrooms="0" sqft="600"/><cl:replyEmail privacy="C">bulkuser@bulkposterz.net</cl:replyEmail><cl:brokerInfo companyName="Joe Sample and Associates" feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" /><title>Spacious Sunny Studio in Upper West Side</title><description><![CDATA[posting body here]]></description></item><item rdf:about="NYCBrokerHousingSample2"><cl:category>fee</cl:category><cl:area>nyc</cl:area><cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea><cl:neighborhood>Chelsea</cl:neighborhood><cl:housingInfo price="2175" bedrooms="1" sqft="850" catsOK="1"/><cl:mapLocation city="New York" state="NY" crossStreet1="23rd Street" crossStreet2="9th Avenue" latitude="40.746492" longitude="-74.001326"/><cl:replyEmail privacy="C" otherContactInfo="212.555.1212">bulkuser@bulkposterz.net</cl:replyEmail><cl:brokerInfo companyName="Joe Sample and Associates" feeDisclosure="fee disclosure here" /><title>1BR Charmer in Chelsea</title><description><![CDATA[posting body goes here]]></description><cl:PONumber>Purchase Order 094122</cl:PONumber></item></rdf:RDF>'

var options = {
  hostname: 'post.craigslist.org',
  path: '/bulk-rss/validate',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("headers: ", res);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.write(posting)
req.end()

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

I am getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type response with the additional message `no element found at line 1, column 0, byte -1`. The xml is taken straight from their example, so it seems like there shouldn't be a problem parsing the xml, unless there is a problem with how I'm sending the https request.

Answer (score 0):

In order to post via the Craigslist bulk posting API, you have to have a PAID account, where you're verified by phone, etc. and you pay per posting. That's likely why it's not working.